# mask entities with Spacy NER?

Tags: nlp, spacy, bert-language-model, named-entity-recognition, topic-modeling

I am working on some topic modeling and my data is heavy on locations. I want to mask them so the model doesn't see them as unique words.

I can find them with Spacy using NER, and this is how I'm currently doing the masking:

```
output_text = []
i = 0

for e in doc.ents: # doc is the spacy doc
    output_text.append(doc[i:e.start].text)
    output_text.append("MASK")
    i = e.end

output_text.append(doc[i:].text)

final_text = ' '.join(output_text)
```

Is there a better (faster) way to accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can try list comprehension:

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
nlp.add_pipe("merge_entities")

text = "Some text."
doc = nlp(text)

final_text = ' '.join("MASK" if token.ent_type_ == "GPE" else token.text for token in doc)

print(final_text)
```